# No implementation Slick DatabaseConfigProvider was bound

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have just created a dummy project and try to integrate Play with Slick. I followed the official tutorial but unfortunatelly did not manage do run it properly. 
Everytime I try to run the app I get following error:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider was bound.
  while locating play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
    for the 1st parameter of com.reciper.repository.UserRepository.<init>(UserRepository.scala:13)
```

Here are my configs:

build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.2"

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.2" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "3.0.3"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "3.0.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.2.4"
```

application.conf

```
play.evolutions {
  autoApply = true
}

#Slick for Play
slick.profile = "slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
slick.db.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.db.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/reciper"
slick.db.user = "postgres"
slick.db.password = "postgres"
```

UserRepository.scala

```
@Singleton
class UserRepository @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
                              (implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[PostgresProfile] { ..codehere.. }
```

HomeController.scala

```
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(repo: UserRepository) {...}
```

plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.13")
```

I have been struggling with it for more than 3 days now and lost my hope that it will actually work.. tried many options, none worked

Do you know what is missing or wrong? Let me know if you need any other file
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following configuration in `application.conf` works

build.sbt

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "3.0.3"
```

application.conf

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-217-243-228.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/d344onl0761ji5"
slick.dbs.default.db.user=user
slick.dbs.default.db.password="pass"
```

Comment: I tried this previously and it didn't work, but now it does. Previously I had dbs.reciper in there (reciper is the name of my DB) and got the error. When I changed evolutions/reciper to evolutions/default both with this config it worked well, thank you a hundred times!